# Why can the results be different from the database on laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-9

I want to ask, why can the results be with other users like the table below for the score, each score must be different.
[image]
So `id_student = 15` with `id_student = 12` the score is 80 the same for all, it should be different from that in the database it should be `id_student = 15` the **score is 100** which is correct as in the database in the ***Assignment_details*** table below:

Table database in MySQL
[image]

***Code:***

**Controller:**

```
public function DataAssignment(){
        $userAssignments = Assignment::join('subjects', 'assignments.id_subject', '=', 'subjects.id_sub')
            ->join('class_infos', 'subjects.id_class', '=', 'class_infos.id')
            ->join('class_details', 'class_infos.id', '=', 'class_details.id_class')
            ->where('class_details.id_user', '=', Auth::user()->id)
            ->get();

        return view('student.index', compact('userAssignments'));
    }
```

**Model:**

```
protected $fillable = [
        'id_id',
        'title',
        'assign_date',
        'due_date',
        'file_asg',
        'id_subject',
    ];

    public function assignments(){
        return $this->belongsTo(AssignmentDetail::class, 'id_id','id_assignment');
    }

    public function nulls(){
        return $this->hasMany(AssignmentDetail::class, 'id_assignment', 'id_id')
                ->where('assignment_details.id_student', '=', Auth::user()->id)
                ->first() === null;
    }
```

**Blade:**

```
@forelse($userAssignments as $data)
                            <tr class="bg-white border-b dark:bg-gray-900 dark:border-gray-700">

                                <th scope="row" class="py-4 px-6 font-medium text-gray-900 whitespace-nowrap dark:text-white">
                                    {{$data->subjects->name_subject}}
                                </th>

                                <td class="w-24 px-6 py-4 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 whitespace-nowrap dark:text-white">
                                    {{$data->title}}
                                </td>
                                <td class="py-4 px-6 font-medium text-gray-900 whitespace-nowrap dark:text-white">
                                    {{ date('d M Y - H:m', strtotime($data->due_date)) }} WIB
                                </td>
                                <td class="py-4 px-6 font-medium text-gray-900 whitespace-nowrap dark:text-white">
                                    @if(!$data->nulls())
                                        {{date('d M Y - H:m' ,strtotime($data->assignments->updated_at))}}
                                    @else
                                        Not uploaded yet
                                    @endif
                                </td>
                                <td class="py-4 px-6 font-medium text-gray-900 whitespace-nowrap dark:text-white">
                                    @if(!$data->nulls())
                                        Submitted
                                    @else
                                        Waiting
                                    @endif
                                </td>
                                <td class="py-4 px-6 font-medium text-gray-900 whitespace-nowrap dark:text-white">
                                    @if(!$data->nulls())
                                        {{ (!empty($data->assignments->score)) ? ($data->assignments->score):'0' }}
                                    @else
                                        0
                                    @endif
                                </td>
                                <td class="py-4 px-6 flex font-medium text-gray-900 whitespace-nowrap dark:text-white">
                                    @if(!$data->nulls())
                                        <a href="{{ (!empty($data->assignments->file_assignment))? url('upload/assignment/students/'.$data->assignments->file_assignment):''}}" download>
                                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-10 w-10" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor">
                                                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M10 18a8 8 0 100-16 8 8 0 000 16zm1-12a1 1 0 10-2 0v4a1 1 0 00.293.707l2.828 2.829a1 1 0 101.415-1.415L11 9.586V6z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
                                            </svg>
                                        </a>
                                    @else

                                    @endif
                                    <a type="button" data-modal-toggle="{{route('input.assignment', $data->id_id)}}">
                                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-10 w-10" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor">
                                            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M6 2a2 2 0 00-2 2v12a2 2 0 002 2h8a2 2 0 002-2V7.414A2 2 0 0015.414 6L12 2.586A2 2 0 0010.586 2H6zm5 6a1 1 0 10-2 0v2H7a1 1 0 100 2h2v2a1 1 0 102 0v-2h2a1 1 0 100-2h-2V8z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
                                        </svg>
                                    </a>

                                    <a href="{{ (!empty($data->file_asg))? url('upload/assignment/question/'.$data->file_asg):url('images/no_image.jpg') }}" download>
                                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-10 w-10" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor">
                                            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M6 2a2 2 0 00-2 2v12a2 2 0 002 2h8a2 2 0 002-2V7.414A2 2 0 0015.414 6L12 2.586A2 2 0 0010.586 2H6zm5 6a1 1 0 10-2 0v3.586l-1.293-1.293a1 1 0 10-1.414 1.414l3 3a1 1 0 001.414 0l3-3a1 1 0 00-1.414-1.414L11 11.586V8z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
                                        </svg>
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        @empty
                            <tr colspan = "7" class="bg-white border-b dark:bg-gray-900 dark:border-gray-700">
                                <td class="py-4 px-6 font-medium text-gray-900 whitespace-nowrap dark:text-white">
                                    No Data
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        @endforelse
```

What is the solution for `id_student = 15` and `id_student = 12` so that they can be on the web according to the database?

Comment: `assignments()` uses a one-to-one relationship, so it's going to grab the first row every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in your model should have One To Many relationship that's mean hasMany, every user may have many score. if right then you must have:

```
public function assignments(){
    return $this->hasMany(AssignmentDetail::class, 'id_id','id_assignment');
}
```